# Multithreading pdf workload slows the program down

Tags: pdf, multiprocessing, pypdf

I tried building a program that scans PDF files to find certain elements and then outputs a new PDF file with all the pages that contain the elements. It was originally single-threaded and a bit slow to run. It took about 36 seconds on a 6-Core-5600X. So I tried multiprocessing it with `concurrent.futures`:

```py
def process_pdf(filename):
    # Open the PDF file
    f = open(filename, "rb")
    print("Searching: " + filename)
    # Create a PDF object
    pdf = PyPDF2.PdfReader(f)

    # Extract the text from each page in the PDF
    extracted_text = [page.extract_text() for page in pdf.pages]

    # Initialize a list
    matching_pages = []

    # Iterate through the extracted text
    for j, text in enumerate(extracted_text):
        # Search for the symbol in the text
        if symbol in text:
            # If the symbol is found, get a new PageObject instance for the page
            page = pdf.pages[j]
            # Add the page to the list
            matching_pages.append(page)

    return matching_pages
```

Multiprocessing Block:

```py
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    # Get a list of the file paths for all PDF files in the directory
    file_paths = [
        os.path.join(directory, filename)
        for filename in os.listdir(directory)
        if filename.endswith(".pdf")
    ]
    futures = [executor.submit(process_pdf, file_path) for file_path in file_paths]

    # Initialize a list to store the results
    results = []

    # Iterate through the futures as they complete
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        # Get the result of the completed future
        result = future.result()
        # Add the result to the list
        results.extend(result)
    # Add each page to the new PDF file
for page in results:
    output_pdf.add_page(page)
```

The multiprocessing works, as evident from the printed text, but it somehow doesn't scale at all. 1 thread ~ 35 seconds, 12 Threads ~ 38 seconds.
Why? Where's my bottleneck?

Tried using other libraries, but most were broken or slower.
Tried using `re` instead of in to search for the symbol, no improvement.

Comment: have you heard about the [GIL](https://realpython.com/python-gil/#the-impact-on-multi-threaded-python-programs)? Python threads can't run at the same time, so in order to have concurrency you must use processes instead: [`concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor)

Comment: How many PDFs do you have? How long did processing take for the slowest PDF (not necessarily the biggest one)?

Answer (score 1):

In general PDF consumes much of a devices primary resources, Each device and system will be different so by way of illustration here is one simple PDF task.

Search for text by a common python library component poppler pdftotext, (others may be faster but the aim here is to show the normal attempts and issues)

As a ballpark yardstick for 1 minute I scanned roughly 2500 pages of one file for the word "AMENDMENTS" found 900 occurrences such as

```
page 82 
[1]  SHORT TITLE OF 1971 AMENDMENTS
[18] SHORT TITLE OF 1970 AMENDMENTS
[44] SHORT TITLE OF 1968 AMENDMENTS
[54] SHORT TITLE OF 1967 AMENDMENTS
page 83 
[11] SHORT TITLE OF 1966 AMENDMENTS
[23] SHORT TITLE OF 1965 AMENDMENTS
[42] SHORT TITLE OF 1964 AMENDMENTS
page 84 
[16] SHORT TITLE OF 1956 AMENDMENTS
[26] SHORT TITLE OF 1948 AMENDMENTS
page 85 
[43] DRUG ABUSE, AND MENTAL HEALTH AMENDMENTS ACT OF 1988
```

to scan the whole file (13,234 pages) would be about 5 mins 20 seconds
and I know from testing **4 cpus could process 1/4 of that file** (3,308 pages from 13,234) **in under 1 minute** (there is a gain for using smaller files).

So a 4 core device should do say 3000 pages per core in a short time, well lets see.

If I thread that as 3 x 1000 pages one finishes after about 50 seconds another about 60 seconds and a 3rd about 70 seconds
overall there is little or just a slight gain, so the cause is one application spending one third of its time in each thread.

- Overall about 3000 pages per minute

Lets try clever lets use 3 applications on the one file. Surely they can each take less time, guess what
one finishes after about 50 seconds another about 60 seconds and a 3rd about 70 seconds no gain using 3 applications

- Overall about 3000 pages per minute

Lets try more clever lets use 3 applications on 3 similar but different files. Surely they can each take less time, guess what
one finishes after about 50 seconds another about 60 seconds and a 3rd about 70 seconds no gain using 3 applications with 3 tasks

- Overall about 3000 pages per minute

Whatever way I try the resources on this device are constrained to Overall about 3000 pages per minute.

I may just as well let 1 thread run un-fettered.

So the basic answer is use multiple devices, same as graphics farming, is done.